# Is it possible to check which gradle dependencies contains given class?

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, dependency-management

Recently we had a version mismatch problem with a class `org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean`. We thought that mismatch is just between some dependency that brings `commons-beanutils` in versions 1.8 and 1.9.3 but after tracking and excluding each transitive dependency we were still facing an issue.

It turns out that the the PropertyUtilsBean was also packed inside the `commons-digester3-3.2-with-deps` instead declared as dependency to `commons-beanutils`.

Is it possible in gradle to search all dependencies (including transitive ones) for specific fully qualified classname? That way we could resolve such problems on the spot.

Answer (score 8):

I tried it and it is possible using some custom gradle build logic:

**Kotlin DSL**

```
tasks {
  val searchClass by creating {
    doLast {
      configurations.forEach {    // check all configurations
        if (it.isCanBeResolved) { 
          try {
            val classLoader = configToClassloader(it)
            // replace here class you are looking for
            val cl = Class.forName("arrow.core.Either", false, classLoader)
            println("found in Configuration $it")
            println(cl.protectionDomain.codeSource.location)
          } catch (e: Exception) {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Helper function: convert a gradle configuration to ClassLoader
fun configToClassloader(config: Configuration) = 
  URLClassLoader(
    config.files.map {
      it.toURI().toURL()
    }.toTypedArray())
```

This could be further enhanced by replacing the hard coded classname with some parameter mechanism.

Sample output:

```
> Task :searchClass
Configuration configuration ':domain:apiDependenciesMetadata'
file:/Users/abendt/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.arrow-kt/arrow-core-data/0.9.0/a5b0228eebd5ee2f233f9aa9b9b624a32f84f328/arrow-core-data-0.9.0.jar
```

**Groovy DSL**

```
def configToClassloader(config) {
  return new URLClassLoader(
          *config.files.collect {
              it.toURI().toURL()
          }.toArray())
}

task searchClass {
  doLast {
    configurations.forEach {    // check all configurations
        if (it.canBeResolved) {
            try {
                def classLoader = configToClassloader(it)
                // replace here class you are looking for
                def cl = Class.forName("arrow.core.Either", false, classLoader)
                println("found in Configuration $it")
                println(cl.protectionDomain.codeSource.location)
            } catch (e) {}
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: I have recently created a Gradle Plugin that provides the described tasks: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.github.redgreencoding.findclass

Comment: this seems promising, but what language are you using here?

Comment: It's the Gradle Kotlin DSL. It's also possible to do it using Groovy

Comment: i have added a Goovy based example too

Answer (score 5):

You could do this

```
task findJarsForClass {
   doLast {
      def findMe = 'org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtilsBean.class'
      def matches = configurations.runtime.findAll { f ->
         f.name.endsWith('.jar') && 
            !(zipTree(f).matching { include findMe }.empty) 
      }
      println "Found $findMe in ${matches*.name}"
   } 
}
```

Comment: How about searching with just the class name instead of the fully qualified class name?

Comment: You could just change `findMe` to `"**/PropertyUtilsBean.class"`

Answer (score 2):

Just <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+left click class name which was imported, then you can see the jar on your ide(eclipse has that feature, probably IntelliJ has as well)

Comment: That was the way we found it but I am curious if there is Gradle specific solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the task [`dependencyInsight`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/inspecting_dependencies.html#sec:identifying_reason_dependency_selection) :

```
gradle -q dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency commons-beanutils
```

> Every Gradle project provides the task dependencyInsight to render the
>   so-called dependency insight report from the command line. Given a
>   dependency in the dependency graph you can identify the selection
>   reason and track down the origin of the dependency selection.

Comment: In this case I want to look for specific class in any of dependency. Something like `yum provides`